# access violation reading location 0x0000000000000001

Tags: c

I am receiving `access violation reading location 0x0000000000000001` error, which breaks in the `memcpy(  src, (double*) data, sizeof(double) );` function. Could anybody help me about it ? Note that mx functions are related about MATLAB in c.

Note that data should be `Short`

Here is the part of my code...

```
Engine *ep;
mxArray *T = NULL;
double *src;
Short data = { 1 };

src = mxGetPr(T);

memcpy(  src, (double*) data, sizeof(double) );

if (!(ep = engOpen(NULL)))
{
    exit(-1);
}

T = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL); 

src = mxGetPr(T);

memcpy(  src, (double*) data, sizeof(double) );

engPutVariable(ep, "T", T);
engEvalString(ep, "T");
```

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you want this code to do. Avoiding the access violation is trivial. Making it actually do what you want depends on what you want. Calling `mxGetPr(T)` when `T == NULL` looks very suspicious. What is this supposed to do?

Comment: There is no language called C/C++. Removing the C++ tag.

Answer (score 8):

The cast `(double*) data` casts the **value** of `data`, yielding `1`. You obviously want the **address** of `data`, though.

After all, you don't need a cast at all.<sup>1</sup> `memcpy` does not care about types; all it needs is pointers and **memory sizes** to determine the amount of memory to be copied.

From `man memcpy`:

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

As you see, `memcpy` takes `void*` pointers, so casting is superflous here. The pointers'll end up as `void*` anyway.
Therefore, just write

```
&data
```

instead.

**Note** this may result in undefined behavior, though; are you sure `Short` and `double` have the same size and alignment properties?
Also, whether you are aware of this or not, using `memcpy` here saves you from violating the strict-aliasing rule. You should know that

```
src = *static_cast<double*>(&data);
```

is undefined behavior if `Short` is not the same as `double`.
(Just so that you know.)

---

Notes:

- Your code looks very C-ish. Sure it's C++?
- In case it's really C++, do not use `T` as an identifier. It is conventionally used for `template` types and any other use may lead to confusion.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to @hvd for your contribution!</sub>

Comment: Hi, Thanks @cad. But this time T is -9.2560e+61 instead of the value of 1

Comment: @cad Don't write any cast at all if it's pointless and risks introducing even more errors. Plain `&data` would suffice, if `memcpy` is needed at all (but based on Cagri's comment, it might not be, it's a bit hard to follow the code).

Comment: Now, the code works well, but the value is wrong. T is -9.2560e+61 instead 1

Comment: @Cagri As hvd said [in a comment to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653557/access-violation-reading-location-0x0000000000000001/35653579?noredirect=1#comment58987732_35653557), it's hard to see what you want to do. The value of `T` seems entirely unrelated to any other variable defined in the given snippet, so either provide more information or figure it out on your own.

Comment: The code starts MATLAB engine session from visual studio. I am trying to assign a value to Short data, and try to see if it really works or not @hvd

Comment: Agree with the folks above. What is the point to copy a bunch of doubles a single `Short`?

Comment: Hi @wesley.mesquita data should be `Short`.

Comment: @hvd Edited. Better now?

Comment: @Cagri We get that. But why would you copy a `Short`, which is, presumably, the same as `short`, to a `double`? That's futile. For testing purposes, you'd be better off with a more realistic example.

Comment: Hi @cad, `typedef       short               Short;`

Comment: @cad Yes, that looks better. Of course, the question is still very unclear so I don't know if you managed to answer it.

Comment: @hvd @cad, thanks for all helps. But I am still sending a wrong value to matlab. I would like to send `short` value (1)  to `matlab` in this example

Answer (score 2):

[man memcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) would have taught you the first argument expected is the *destination*. Plus your casting is wrong:

```
memcpy( &data, src, sizeof(double) );
```